# Play framework, PostgreSQL in memory database, interval not working

Tags: postgresql, playframework, h2

I can't get the following request to work with Play framework

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableName 
    FROM hand 
    WHERE (hand.userLogin = {userLogin} OR {userLogin} IS NULL)
    AND (date >= now() - interval '3 days')
    ORDER BY tableName
```

I tested it on a PostreSQL database and it works perfectly, however when I try to run in in dev mode it does not work, I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT DISTINCT TABLENAME        FROM HAND        WHERE (HAND.USERLOGIN = ? OR ? IS NULL)       AND (DATE >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3 minute'[*])       ORDER BY TABLENAME "; expected "., (, [, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, (, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )";

my conf file says:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=PostgreSQL"
```

I don't know what I am getting wrong.
Removing the interval part makes it work so it is obviously the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres interval does not belong to H2 standard, thus it is not supported by H2. See [h2 grammar doc](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html) for supported functions and keywords.

Comment: And is there a way to write this so H2 and PostgreSQL would understand it ? I can't find any.
The H2 way looks like this:

    SELECT DISTINCT tableName        
    FROM hand        
    WHERE date >= DATESUB('MINUTE', 3, NOW())
    ORDER BY tableName

Comment: Try this `SELECT DISTINCT tableName FROM hang WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);`

Comment: H2 does not like it neither: 
Function "DATE_SUB" not found.

I think I will just install a postgres DB on my Dev environment, that will avoid problems.

Comment: I find H2 really limited, thus I have dev mysql installation as well as UAT. If you use JPA with Play!, try using JPA API for date functions rather than pure database specific SQL. Hopefully it will solve your problems.

Comment: The "interval" data type has been part of SQL standards since at least 1992. PostgreSQL has supported SQL intervals since at least version 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

H2 doesn't support interval data types, but PostgreSQL does.

**Standard SQL and PostgreSQL**

Standard SQL quotes the number, but not the qualifier. In this context, the qualifier is always singular, not plural. (As in *day*, not *days*.)

```
select current_date - interval '3' day;
```

PostgreSQL allows variations of that, including `interval '3 day'` and `interval '3 days'`. But it doesn't allow these trailing brackets, which appear in your error message. (I suppose those brackets might be simply part of the error message, though.)

```
INTERVAL '3 minute'[*]
```

You might also be getting a spurious error message related to the use of a reserved word as a column name. (The word *date* is a reserved word.)

You can test *standard* syntax at the [Mimer SQL Validation Services](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm) web site.

**H2**

H2 doesn't support interval data types. ([*Interval* isn't in this list](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html).) Its [datediff() function returns a long integer](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#datediff), not an interval.

**What to do**

If your production dbms is PostgreSQL, you should probably use PostgreSQL in development and testing, too.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing :) Thanks